# Rewind prints file elements second time

Tags: c, file, project

I am trying a C language program, but facing some difficulty.
Problem: I use file in my project but when I rewind my file1 then it duplicate same data in file2. How can I solve this problem?

You can refer the code below.

```
void calculate_bill ()
{
    system("cls");
    int quan,q;
    printf("Enter the number of item : ");
    scanf("%d",&quan);
    char sell[100];
    float total=0,gtotal=0;
    file1=fopen("object.txt","r");
    file2=fopen("temp.txt","w");
    //printf("SN\tITEM NAME\tCODE\tRATE\t\tQUANTITY\tTOTAL\n");
    rewind(file1);
    for(int i=1;i<=quan;i++)
    {
        rewind(file1);
        printf("Enter the item name : ");
        scanf("%s",&sell);
        printf("Enter the item quantity : ");
        scanf("%d",&q);
        while(fscanf(file1,"%s %d %f %d",&object.name,&object.code,&object.rate,&object.quantity)!=EOF)
        {
            if(strcmp(sell,object.name)==0)
            {
            total=object.rate*q;
            gtotal=gtotal+total;
            object.quantity=object.quantity-q;
            fprintf(file2,"%s\t\t%d\t%f\t%d\n",object.name,object.code,object.rate,object.quantity);
            }
            else
            fprintf(file2,"%s\t\t%d\t%f\t%d\n",object.name,object.code,object.rate,object.quantity);
        }
    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    remove("object.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","object.txt");
    printf("The total amount is : %.2f",gtotal);
    getch();
    system("cls");
    d_mainmenu();
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
SN      ITEM NAME       CODE    RATE            QUANTITY
1       abed            105     100.000000      7

2       maruf           100     100.000000      9

3       adi             106     100.000000      10

4       anik            89      1.000000        1

5       abed            105     100.000000      8

6       maruf           100     100.000000      9

7       adi             106     100.000000      9

8       anik            89      1.000000        1

9       abed            105     100.000000      8

10      maruf           100     100.000000      9

11      adi             106     100.000000      10

12      anik            89      1.000000        0
```

I need Output Like this ...

```
SN      ITEM NAME       CODE    RATE            QUANTITY
1       abed            105     100.000000      7

2       maruf           100     100.000000      9

3       adi             106     100.000000      10

4       anik            89      1.000000        1
```

after using this function.

Comment: Every time you enter something, you're appending all entries to the output. I think you would be better off first reading all your data into a suitable structure, then modifying the data, then writing the updated data when you're done with it.

Comment: cna you give me a sample code sir?

Comment: What is your expectation? do you want to reduce object quantity from object.file ?

Answer (score 0):

> ... but when i rewind my file1 then it duplicate same data in file2

Well, it's **not** `rewind` that duplicate the data. In your `while` you print every line from file1 to the end of file2. So if the `for` loop is executed 3 times, file2 will contained 3 times the contents of file1 (with some lines modified).

The easiest way to fix the code you have now, is probably to stop using `rewind` and instead do the `open`, `close` and `rename` inside the `for` loop.

Like:

```
for(int i=1;i<=quan;i++)
{
    file1=fopen("object.txt","r");
    file2=fopen("temp.txt","w");

    printf("Enter the item name : ");
    ...
    ...
    while(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    remove("object.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","object.txt");
}
```

That said you should consider a new design where you first read all of file1 into memory (i.e. into an array of your object type). Then modify the value of the array elements and finally write the values back to a file.